# Showing a dialog on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a part of my page:

```
<link href="scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="scripts/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/jscript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div>

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/HeaderBar.png" CssClass="header" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/title.PNG" CssClass="Title" />
            <img alt="" class="logo" src="Images/ECON_76px.png" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="VersionText" Text="Version {0}"></asp:Label>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLogOff" runat="server" CssClass="lbLogOff" ToolTip="Close your current session">Log off</asp:LinkButton>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbReset" runat="server" CssClass="lbReset" OnClientClick="ShowDialog();" ToolTip="Restart your session as if you would just have logged in">Restart</asp:LinkButton>

            <asp:Label ID="lblTestDB" runat="server" CssClass="lblTestDB" Text="CONNECTED TO TEST DATABASE"></asp:Label>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>


        <div id="dialog" title="Restart">
            <p>This will clear all data of the current session (as if you would have just logged in)!</p>
            <p>Are you sure?</p>
            <input id="yes" type="button" value="Yes" />
            <input id="no" type="button" value="No" />
        </div>

        <script type="text/jscript">
            function ShowDialog() {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    buttons:
                    {
                        "Yes": function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); return false; }
                        , "No": function () { return true; }
                    }
                }).prev().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            }
        </script>

    </form>
</body>
```

The idea is to show a dialog when the restart button is clicked as I don't like the alert box of Chrome.

Why does it not work?
Kind of took it straight from an example in a book.

Comment: Is there any output in the browser console? Errors most likely. You'll want to make sure jQuery and jQuery UI are being loaded properly. From looking at your code, you're loading jQuery twice (once with a version-named file, once without), and all with type `text/jscript` which should be `text/javascript`. Also make sure you're including the jQuery UI CSS, otherwise the dialog won't render properly.

Comment: I have added the two CSS lines to the post. They were in the file as well.

Comment: In the dialog example, the buttons were added by the dialog control: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation  Don't know if that is part of the issue.  Could you elaborate on what specifically doesn't work?  When you click the button, or the dialog doesn't show, or it doesn't appear right in Chrome, or...?

Comment: Nothing shows. I did swap the two links for the jquery libraries though. apparently you need to load jquery before jquery-ui. Now the dialog shows, but with to many buttons :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't loading any jQuery UI CSS libraries, and you are loading 2 versions of normal jQuery. As a quick test, try removing your own jQuery libraries and link to Google to get you started. You can then gradually place yours back:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

A side note, you are mixing type "jscript" and "javascript". As of HTML5, you can simply leave off specifying type declarations. It will be assumed to be CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: I can see now the dialog when I click on the button. So that works. But the div with the dialog content is also visible before the dialog is shown. How do I prevent it? Setting visibility of the div to hidden also hides it from the dialog.

Comment: found it: set style "display: none"

Comment: That works, but as an FYI, the jQuery UI way of hiding elements is to use class="ui-helper-hidden". That will hide it from screen readers too.

Answer (score 1):

There it needs some changes in your code. Try this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                buttons:
                {
                    "Yes": function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); return false; }
                    , "No": function () { return true; }
                }
            }).prev().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        });

        function ShowDialog() {
            $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        }
    </script>
```